# How do I add a namespace when creating a new c++ class?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, namespaces

I right click in my solution and select add class, then c++ class and enter a name but I need to be able tof define a namespaceace because the object I'm creating has the same name as another object in my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your class into

```
namespace my_name_space {
    class my_class {
    //...
    };
}
```

?

Comment: I tried putting my existing class into a namespace like this but was still getting the object already exists error. So there'should no way to define the namespace when creating the class?

Comment: What you're asking for is what this does.  It seems like you need to post your code for us to understand your issue.

Comment: You just can't get an error like "object already exists" by wrapping your class into a namespace. An object is not a class.

Comment: I'm learning  and the instructor is using Eclipse as an ìde which let's him create a .h and .cpp with a namespace all at once. I guess I have to create the .house and .cpp files separately then assign the namespace

Comment: .house=.h...autocoorect

Comment: This is not an IDE problem. You seem to have a misconception about `.h` and `.cpp` files which cannot be "created in a namespace". It is only the class or the method declaration that may be surrounded by a namespace.